# share pdf file using UIActivityViewController in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController to share a PDF file:

```
let pdfFilePath = URL(string: "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_tutorial.pdf")
let pdfData = NSData(contentsOf: pdfFilePath!)
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData!], applicationActivities: nil)

present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The below result is displayed:

[image]

What I want is to display more features like "copy to Books" and "Add to Notes" like the following:

[image]

Comment: Try passing `pdfFilePath` instead of `pdfData` to the activity view controller.

Comment: I tried it but id didn't work

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share your pdf file which is on the server and you have a URL. Then first you download that file in your device and then share that file to any other person.

If you using `Alamofire` in your code then there is code.

**Stape 1**

```
import Alamofire
```

**Stape 2**

Add this function in your class:-

```
func downloadPdf(downloadUrl : String, fileName: String, completionHandler:@escaping(String, Bool)->()){

        let destinationPath: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0];
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).pdf")
            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }
        print(downloadUrl)
        Alamofire.download(downloadUrl, to: destinationPath)
            .downloadProgress { progress in

            }
            .responseData { response in
                print("response: \(response)")
                switch response.result{
                case .success:
                    if response.destinationURL != nil, let filePath = response.destinationURL?.absoluteString {
                        completionHandler(filePath, true)
                    }
                    break
                case .failure:
                    completionHandler("", false)
                    break
                }
        }
    }
```

**Stape 3**

Add this action on your share button

```
@IBAction func btnShareAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let myURL = "http://www.demo.com/demo.pdf"  // change this with your URL
        self.downloadPdf(downloadUrl : myURL, fileName: "invoice") { (localFileUrl, bool) in

             let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localFileUrl)
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

          }
      }
```

Comment: hi I m getting issue when activity controller open of default mail app and its not attaching pdf in it. its working for gmail app and outlook as well. Please provide suggestion . I am really stuck on it.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Steps! Copy paste the give code

```
@objc private func btnShareTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let urlString = strURL,
          let url = URL(string: urlString),
          let docPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last else {
        return
    }
    let actualPath = docPath.appendingPathComponent("Statement.pdf")
    let pdfData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url)

    do {
        try pdfData?.write(to: actualPath, options: .atomic)
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: actualPath.absoluteString)
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL],
                                                  applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityVC, animated: true)
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Pdf could not be saved")
    }
}
```

Comment: This will freeze your UI during upload

Comment: I tried with my end, not freezing. Is it freezing for you? May be big pdf files we have to add loading indicator.

Comment: It is conceptually incorrect to call Data.init(contentsOf: url) on a main thread, if that is a network resource's URL. As well as to copy large files by doing data.write(to: path)